# Export data from given SQL Server query path to excel using cammand prompt

Tags: sql-server, cmd

I have a SQL Server query path and I have to export data to Excel using cammand prompt.

This is cmd query:

```
sqlcmd -S "Server name" -U "Username" -P "Password" 
       -d "DBname" -i "Query_path.sql" -o "File_path.xls"
```

but this add all data in one column but I have to export data to Excel with proper format.

So how can we set proper Excel format according to data using cmd?

Comment: You need to **at LEAST** show us the table structure(s) involved, some sample data, the **query** you're using to run against that data, and please also provide the **desired output** from that query

Comment: `sqlcmd` executes queries. It doesn't export data. Just because it can output stuff to a file doesn't make it an export tool. Why aren't you using the `Import\Export wizard`? It's already available as a menu item in the Management Studio. The last page even allows you to save what you created as a script for later execution

Comment: When in doubt, read the documentation or at least search for an answer. You'll find that SQL Server has an entire service for ETL, not just exporting XLSX files. The documentation has entire sections for it, there are dozens of books, hundreds of courses and thousands of articles on SSIS